# How to change ip table permanently on android device?

Tags: android, routes, ip

I have android with two network interface `wlan0` and `eth0`.

Interface `eth0` is connected with some private network (without internet).

Interface `wlan0` is the source of Internet of my device.

The problem is when activate `eth0` ethernet port of the device the internet coming from the wifi stops to work, there are routing problems.

I did some routing configuration command and am able to solve it.

```
ip route add table eth0 default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlan0 proto static
```

The issue  is, when I restart the kiosk the config disappears so, I have to do it again each time.

Can you tell me how can I change permanently ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you managed this issue? I have the same

Comment: Yes, I requested a new version from the provider and it solved the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks it's not my case))